# jquery move element to inside new element

Tags: jquery, insert, element, createelement

For example I have code:

HTML:

```
...<input type="text">...
```

And I would like get this input (I can have more inputs) and 'insert' in to new created element e.g `<div>` in the same place.

Result:

```
...<div><input type="text"></div>...
```

This code working half correctly, because it inserts  input to new element, but with 'copy' all input from page.

jQuery:

```
$('input').after('<div class="inp_cont"/>').append("div.inp_cont");
```

I tried with `.detach()`

```
$('input').after('<div class="inp_cont"/>').detach().append("div.inp_cont");
```

This creates a new element, but don't insert `input` inside.

I haven't idea how resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `wrap()`:

```
$('input').wrap('<div class="inpt_cont"></div>');
```

```js
$('input').wrap('<div class="inpt_cont"></div>');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input />
<input />
<input />
```

If you want to wrap all elements, matched by the same selector, with the same element:

```
$('input').wrapAll('<div class="inpt_cont"></div>');

$('input').wrap('<div class="inpt_cont"></div>');
```

```js
$('input').wrapAll('<div class="inpt_cont"></div>');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input />
<input />
<input />
```

References:

- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).
- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).