# How to make a child the parent of it's parent using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this

```
<div class="a" foo="bar">
  <div class="b">
    <!-- various things here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to transform it into this:

```
<div class="b">
  <div class="a" foo="bar">
    <!-- various things here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

using jQuery. How would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - signs of prior research and effort is an absolute requirement by SO guidelines. SO is for specific programming questions that have been researched and trialled but STILL unable to fix, **not** a replacement for a tutorial. Find any jquery tutorial and do that first, then search for 'jquery change parent' or similar if still having issues - absolutely no need nor benifit to yet another no-research topic like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery move element to inside new element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495862/jquery-move-element-to-inside-new-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve the `events` and handlers, use `clone()`:

```js
$(function () {
  a = $(".a").clone();
  a.find(".b").remove().end().html($(".b").html());
  $(".b").unwrap().html("").append(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" foo="bar">
  <div class="b">
    <!-- various things here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @charlietfl Check again? I have updated the code.

Comment: This doesn't work for me; I get the content as a child of `b`, and `a` as another child, eg `<div class="b"><!--various things here--> <div class="a" foo="bar"></div></div>` on firefox 41 with jquery 1.9.1

Comment: @Shel Right... Lemme correct it.

Comment: @Shel Works now. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Without any specific criteria other than html shown can do:

```
$('.a').html( $('.b').html()).wrap('<div class="b">');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/daszdmg9/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is technically correct... the best kind of correct (but Praveen still gets the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use it as follows...

```
$('.b').insertBefore($('.a'));
$('.b').append($('.a'));
```

Comment: in place .html('') you can pass a variable which has your additional html code

Comment: I was too quick to upvote; this doesn't work.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake and now I changed it. And it will work exactly the way you want.

Comment: Do you have a habit of marking it up when it is wrong and mark it down when it is right?

Comment: No, your answer still doesn't work; I reverted my mistaken upvote. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/r14fga48/

Comment: Well it is working from your own example. I got the below thing by using inspect element in chrome from your jsfiddel example.
<body>
  <div class="b">
    various things here
     <div class="a" foo="bar">
     </div>
   </div>
</body>. Please observe the html structure. I believe this is your requirement, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, it should be `<div class="b"><div class="a" foo="bar"> various things here </div></div>` as show in my original question.